# Describe a multiple range parameter with Swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I want to describe in Swagger 2.0 a parameter defined as follows :

- The parameter takes a valid value in the intervals : **-20 < parameter < -10** or **0 < parameter < 30**
- The parameter is invalid if : **-10 ≤ parameter ≤ 0**

This means that it has two valid intervals and thus **two max and mins values to define**.
Does Swagger specification support that kind of definitions?

Comment: Related: [How does one indicate that a number is prohibited for use in Swagger documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60657280/113116)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be described in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0, but can be described in OpenAPI 3.x using `oneOf`.

#### OpenAPI 3.0

```yaml
type: integer
oneOf:
  - minimum: -20
    maximum: -10
    exclusiveMinimum: true
    exclusiveMaximum: true
  - minimum: 0
    maximum: 30
    exclusiveMinimum: true
    exclusiveMaximum: true
```

#### OpenAPI 3.1

```yaml
type: integer
oneOf:
  - exclusiveMinimum: -20
    exclusiveMaximum: -10
  - exclusiveMinimum: 0
    exclusiveMaximum: 30
```

`exclusiveM*` keywords were [changed from boolean to numbers](https://json-schema.org/draft-06/json-schema-release-notes.html#q-what-are-the-changes-between-draft-04-and-draft-06) in JSON Schema Draft 6. OAS 3.1 uses JSON Schema 2020-12 by default.

Comment: Thank you .. That was very useful .. Do you know how can this be translated in Spring Annotations?

Comment: @SaraSara I don't know, sorry. Feel free to [ask a new question](/questions/ask?tags=java+spring+swagger) about this.