# How does one indicate that a number is prohibited for use in swagger documentation?

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am trying to specify a property in my swagger documentation called `myNumber`, which can be any integer in [-1, 10] except 0. This is what I have so far:

```
myNumber:
    type: integer
    description: You can use any number in [-1, 10] except 0.
    minimum: -1
    maximum: 10
```

How can I be explicit that `0` is prohibited? I haven't found any specification for this in the openAPI docs. Is this even possible?

Comment: Related: [Describe a multiple range parameter with Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58874658/113116)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1: enum

If the list of possible values is small, you can list them all in an `enum`:

```yaml
myNumber:
  type: integer
  description: You can use any number in [-1, 10] except 0.
  enum: [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

This is the easiest solution and works in both OpenAPI 2.0 and 3.x.

#### Option 2: oneOf

In OpenAPI 3.x you can use `oneOf` to define two ranges of possible values:

```yaml
myNumber:
  type: integer
  description: You can use any number in [-1, 10] except 0.
  oneOf:
    - enum: [-1]  # shorthand for `minimum: -1` + `maximum: -1`
    - minimum: 1
      maximum: 10
```

In OpenAPI 3.1 you can replace `enum: [-1]` with `const: -1`.

#### Option 3: not

OpenAPI 3.x also supports `not` to define conditions that an instance *must not* meet. For example, you exclude the value 0 as follows:

```yaml
myNumber:
  type: integer
  description: You can use any number in [-1, 10] except 0.
  minimum: -1
  maximum: 10
  not:
    enum: [0]
```

In OpenAPI 3.1 you can replace `enum: [0]` with `const: 0`.

However, actual tooling support for `not` may vary.

Comment: Just curious: Is there a way to accomplish this assuming the range can have a high upper bound, such as 10000, in swagger 2.0?

Comment: Other than `enum` - no.